# What is the grammar rule for "might + verb1, and verb2"?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

> Exposing individuals' personal data might make them vulnerable to
>   cyber fraud and piracy, which might result in them losing money and
>   **put/puts** their privacy at risk.

**When I write might + verb1, and verb2, should I treat verb2 as if it was preceded with might? and what is this rule called?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use *puts*, that is a tensed verb, and has to be interpreted as parallel with *might*:

> which [might result in them losing money] and [puts their privacy at risk].

so it is stating that it *does* put their privacy at risk. This is probably not what you intended.

If you use *put*, then it is not a tensed verb, so it must be inside the scope of "might":

> which might [[result in them losing money] and [put their privacy at risk]]

This distinction only appears in the 3rd person singular ("he/she/it puts"). In any other person, there would be no distinction, and the sentence would be formally ambiguous (eg *those things might result in them losing money and put their privacy at risk.* ) Only context (and real world knowledge) can then resolve the ambiguity.